# Somethings wrong with my javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a page that you type in something in the `textbox` and the page will alert the text in the `textbox` but look at the function alert it's not working please help!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function alert() {
      var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value;
      var email = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_b gb_7a gb_R gb_3a").innerHTML;
      window.alert("From: ", +email + " Message: " + userInput);
    }
  </script>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <input id="1" type="text" value="Write what you want the page to say">
  <button onclick="alert()">Enter</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check console for errors.. Why function name is `alert` ?

Comment: where is the element with class "gb_b gb_7a gb_R gb_3a" in teh form?

Comment: @gurvinder372, That is a valid syntax! `document.getElementsByClassName(names);`

Comment: this is element is from google docs to get the users email.
im trying to make an addon test project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the custom function into `alertFunction()` since it is causing conflict with javascript built-in `alert()` function.

Try the following code:

```html
<script>
    function alertFunction() {
      var userInput = document.getElementById("inputid1").value;
      var email = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_b gb_7a gb_R gb_3a").innerHTML;
      alert("From: " +email + " Message: " + userInput);
    }
</script>
<base target="_top">

<body>
  <input id="inputid1" type="text" value="Write what you want the page to say">
  <button onclick="alertFunction();">Enter</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `alert()` recursively without any exit condition, as `window.alert` refers to your implementation of `alert()` itself.
If you look into your console's log you will see call stack exceeded error.

```
 function alert() {
     var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value;
     var email = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_b gb_7a gb_R gb_3a").innerHTML;
     alert("From: " + email + "Message: " +userInput); //This refers to your alert
}
```

You should rename the function as suggested in comments or if you want to override the default behaviour of the alert() function then do not call it from inside of your function.

```
function custom_alert() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("1").value;
  var email = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_b gb_7a gb_R gb_3a").innerHTML;
  //window.alert("From: ", +email + " Message: " + userInput);
  console.log("From: "+email + " Message: " + userInput);

}
```